# BroadcastReceiver resets itself I think, I need it run without resetting

Tags: javascript, java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a big homework for tomorrow and I'm stuck with 1 thing. Basically what I need to do is counting SMS' that incoming to my phone. For example if someone sends me an sms and it says "A" program will count it and will pop-up a toast message saying: "Answer A":1 and when another SMS came it will go for "Answer A":2. I did some code work but it shows up for 1 even if I sent 20 "A" SMS'. I think it resets itself after counting first SMS. There are my codes.

```
public class SmsAlici extends BroadcastReceiver {
   public int sayacA = 0, sayacB = 0, sayacC = 0, sayacD = 0;
    public int toplam = 0;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)

    {
            SmsMessage[] mesaj = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
            SmsMessage sms = mesaj[0];
            String gonderen = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
            String sms_icerik = sms.getMessageBody();


            sms_icerik = sms_icerik.trim();


            if (sms_icerik.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                sayacA++;
                toplam++;
                Toast.makeText(context, "A Cevabı:" + Integer.toString(sayacA), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (sms_icerik.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                sayacB++;
                toplam++;
                Toast.makeText(context, "B Cevabı:" + Integer.toString(sayacB), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (sms_icerik.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                sayacC++;
                toplam++;
                Toast.makeText(context, "C Cevabı:" + Integer.toString(sayacC), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (sms_icerik.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                sayacD++;
                toplam++;
                Toast.makeText(context, "D Cevabı: " + Integer.toString(sayacD), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }


            if (toplam == 20) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "A Cevabı Toplamı: " + Integer.toString(sayacA), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, "B Cevabı Toplamı: " + Integer.toString(sayacB), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, "C Cevabı Toplamı: " + Integer.toString(sayacC), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, "D Cevabı Toplamı: " + Integer.toString(sayacD), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                toplam = 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark next to it. This will help the answerer (reputation points), will help you (improves your "accept-rate") and will help others who have a similar problem. It will also remove the question ftom the list of questions without accepted answers.

Answer (score 0):

After each SMS you receive, probably android is instantiating a new instance of your class.

Change:

```
public int sayacA = 0, sayacB = 0, sayacC = 0, sayacD = 0;
```

to :

```
public static int sayacA = 0, sayacB = 0, sayacC = 0, sayacD = 0;
```

But, the best solution is to persist these values on SharedPreferences. This way, you prevent to loose data if the app is killed.

Take a look at: [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)